# Why is the Mail Server Configuration hidden for my JFrog Platform admin?

Tags: artifactory, mail-server, jfrog-xray, jfrog-container-registry

I try to set up JFrogs Mail Server Configuration according to this article:

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JCR6X/Mail+Server+Configuration

Unfortunately I can't find the Configuration | Mail section within my admin account.

The Administration Menu looks like this for me:
[Administration  Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAnEP.png)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a jcr version 7.x and to get into the mail config, navigate to JCR UI --> Administration --> General | Mail Server as below,
[image]

And add the mail config.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just added an image to my Original Post. I only got Settings and Webhooks as options! Mail Server is not visible for me. Any further ideas?

Comment: @AndyReichel It seems you are using the JFrog Cloud so Mail Server is out of the box and cannot be customized

Comment: Hi @TalEtinger. Thanks a lot! That makes sense. But how come that my Mail Notifications are not properly executed?

Comment: @AndyReichel Can you describe the use-case? Did you check the logs?

Comment: @TalEtinger The use-case is simple. We configure a new watch for example. We add email receivers to the watch. We do a history scan (Apply watch on existing content). No Mail arrives. No Mail is filtered (Spam). Seems no mail was sent from the out of the box Mail Server Configuration. Thanks!